# ROS + Morse launch error 8

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-lunar, morse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I just picked up ROS and Morse and I'm trying to follow the Morse's tutorial on ROS Navigation. The tutorial can be found [here](http://www.openrobots.org/morse/doc/latest/user/advanced_tutorials/ros_nav_tutorial.html). On the part that say to edit the file *nav.launch*, I followed what is said there, but when I run the command `roslaunch morse_2dnav nav.launch` I get a error *OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error* and I'm having a hard time solving this issue. Any help? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3, Morse Simulator v 1.2, ROS Lunar.

Edit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 318, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 271, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 220, in _start_infrastructure
    self._load_config()
  File "/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 135, in _load_config
    roslaunch_strs=self.roslaunch_strs, verbose=self.verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 451, in load_config_default
    loader.load(f, config, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 750, in load
    self._load_launch(launch, ros_config, is_core=core, filename=filename, argv=argv, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 722, in _load_launch
    self._recurse_load(ros_config, launch.childNodes, self.root_context, None, is_core, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 666, in _recurse_load
    self._param_tag(tag, context, ros_config, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 95, in call
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 266, in _param_tag
    value = self.param_value(verbose, name, ptype, *vals)
  File "/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/loader.py", line 492, in param_value
    p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

My launch file, as described on the tutorial:

```
<launch>
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find morse_mcl)/robot.urdf" />
   <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />
</launch>
```

The `lsb_release -a` output is:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282607/ros-+-morse-launch-error-8/) by [mrphaell](https://answers.ros.org/users/33693/mrphaell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-02-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-13**:
Can you please be a bit more specific? What exactly are you changing, and please copy-paste the entire error message (including the stack trace) into your question. Use the `edit` button/link.

Know that ROS+Morse is not a frequently used combination, so getting answers may take a while.

**Comment by [mrphaell](https://answers.ros.org/users/33693/mrphaell/) on 2018-02-13**:
The changes are the one the tutorial specify (create the launch file and write the launch tags). I'll edit my question and post the exact launch file and the trace of the error. I'm trying to implement Monte Carlo Localization, do you know a better/easier combination to use?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
Don't use `<pre>` tags for code, but indent it by 4 spaces. Use the *Preformatted Text* button for that (the one with `101010` on it). Select the code, press the button (or `ctrl+k`).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
Were you instructed to create any Python scripts? If so: are they executable? Do they start with `#!/usr/bin/env python`?

If not: how did you install ROS? Where did the `robot_state_publisher` come from?

(also: `state_publisher` is deprecated, please use `robot_state_publisher`)

**Comment by [mrphaell](https://answers.ros.org/users/33693/mrphaell/) on 2018-02-14**:
To run the simulation only on Morse it's needed a Python script, but it already have the `#!/usr/bin/env python`. I followed the instructions on [ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Ubuntu) to install ROS. I'll look if can be an error with the `state_publisher` being deprecated.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:\

> I'll look if can be an error with the `state_publisher` being deprecated

no, that shouldn't be the problem.

The `Exec format error` is typically seen if you try to start a script (with `bash` or another shell) and that doesn't specify which interpreter should be used. RSP is a C++ program.

**Comment by [mrphaell](https://answers.ros.org/users/33693/mrphaell/) on 2018-02-14**:
I see. The files listed on the error (`__init__.py`, `parent.py`, `config.py`, `xmlloader.py`, `loader.py` and `subprocess.py`) don't have that. Could that be it?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
No. They are all Python modules, not top-level scripts.

The problem is most likely with something that the launch file is trying to start (ie: a `node` or a script started as a `node`). You could remove and add single lines to see which one is causing the problem.

**Comment by [mrphaell](https://answers.ros.org/users/33693/mrphaell/) on 2018-02-14**:
I removed and added single lines, the problem persists. If I remove the `node` it gives the same output. If I remove the `param`, the `robot_description` couldný be found. I changed the `$(find morse_mcl)/robot.urdf` to the absolute path (was concerned with the `find`), still nothing.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
Can you `roslaunch` any launch file? What is the output `lsb_release -a` (please add it to your original question text, use the `edit` button/link for that).

**Comment by [mrphaell](https://answers.ros.org/users/33693/mrphaell/) on 2018-02-14**:
I used other launch file, from `amcl` package, and went ok, no errors. I used the `amcl_omni.launch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> <param name="robot_description" command="$(find morse_mcl)/robot.urdf" />
> ```

This is most likely your problem.

`roslaunch` expects an actual command in the `command` attribute (ie: a program it can start).

`find` will return the absolute path to the urdf, and the urdf is not a program. Hence the error.

Note btw that the tutorial you link actually has the following in `command`:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="cat $(find morse_2dnav)/pr2.urdf"/>
```

note the `cat` there. That is a program, and should work.

However, I would recommend the following, which is a bit more 'modern':

```
<param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find morse_2dnav)/pr2.urdf" />
```

Note that this only works because `pr2.urdf` is an actual urdf. If it were a [xacro](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro), you'd need `command` again (to start `xacro`).

See also the [roslaunch/xml/param](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param) documentation.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
Btw, I just looked at the tutorial you link and it is *very old*. Most of the instructions there are outdated (rosbuild vs catkin, `manifest.xml` vs `package.xml`, editing `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` by hand, etc). It can probably still be made to work, but following those instructions literally may ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
.. cause you some trouble.

**Comment by [mrphaell](https://answers.ros.org/users/33693/mrphaell/) on 2018-02-14**:
I'm aware of that, but I'm making some modifications to make it work, since the tutorial is providing me the base to build what I need.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
Would perhaps be nice to also update the tutorial page then?

**Comment by [mrphaell](https://answers.ros.org/users/33693/mrphaell/) on 2018-02-14**:
Yeah, I'll look into it.